# LaTeX (using MikTeX 2.9) vs. PDFLaTeX

Tags: pdftex

Please advise which is best match for typesetting `PDFLaTeX` or `LaTeX`. I have recommend that `LaTeX`, dvi to PS and Ps to PDF, but some of my friends suggested that to go to `PDFLaTeX` for getting the PDF output directly from TeX files.

Please share your valuable suggestions regarding this...

Thanks to all...

Comment: Using `pdflatex` is so much more flexible & convenient, in my mind, plus it allows pdf specials, when occasionally needed.  When importing figures (many types rather than just `eps`), it is also much more portable.  Don't know if it still an issue, but at one point, `dvi` rendering had issues with background color as well as rotated items. Not so with `pdflatex`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is answerable as it stands: to some extent this is a matter of opinion. There are objective parts, for example DVI routes allow PostScript manipulation, PDF routes enable some font/hyperlink/... effects that are hard to do using DVI.